# Help identifying scooter hub motor components related to temperature

Tags: motor, sensor, identification, temperature

I got a Jetson Bio scooter because it was not working (still isn't).  It exhibited a notchy hub motor when pushed by foot.  After taking it apart I found that the MOSFET for one of the motor phases was shorted so I replaced that.

I then noticed that the display was still reporting thermal issues E10 code referenced [here](https://support.ridejetson.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026456211-Why-does-my-Jetson-Bio-Ion-scooter-have-an-error-code-?source=search).  I'm assuming that during the short condition the temperature sensor(s) / resistor(s) overheated.

The controller the scooter uses is [PAC5223QM](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/412/PAC5223_Data_Sheet-1714871.pdf) (If this is helpful).

[image: Front]

White wire is temperature sensor, and coming from the controller I measured ~2.1V.

[image: Back]

Triangular point is the Negative terminal

[image: Closeup]

All I can see is the "G1" marking on the component but that doesn't show any results in google.  I have no idea what these might be or how to even test them if they are functioning properly.

Comment: We don't really answer repair questions here, we can answer component ID questions. Please reduce your question to only the ID portion, and provide dimensions of the part and possibly ohm it out.

Comment: Those are more likely the Hall sensors, nothing to do with temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to a local electronics shop and they tipped me off to these being transistors.  Looking for "G1" transistors finally led me to the correct parts, specifically **MMBT5551**.  I purchased [these](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Comchip-Technology/MMBT5551-G?qs=2qJf6qQ4IOJMYyydTk7L6w%3D%3D) as replacements.  They are SOT23 dimensions and their resistance was ~3.5MOhm.

I gave the extra detail in my original post because I figured context would help with identifying the component.  For posterity, I'll also now leave the extra info that this was actually not what was causing the temperature code E10.  It seems I mis-soldered the gate on the broken MOSFET I originally replaced.  The fact that the gate was open circuit throws the same "temperature" error on these controllers.